# Text To Speech - To say price amount Android

Tags: android, text-to-speech

In my app, I want to tell the price of a product to the user using Text To Speech.

Example: The statement that the system should speak is "The price of this product is ₹.125.50". In this, ₹.125.50 should be spoken as 125 Rupees and 50 paise or Rupees 125 and 50 paise.

Is there any way to achieve this using TTS or by other means?

Comment: taking a glance at it one way to achive this is change the string itself while passing it to the tts engine... i.e show "The price of this product is ₹.125.50". to the user if needed and pass the 125 Rupees and 50 paise or Rupees 125 and 50 paise to tts engine

Comment: yes it is possible, but you forgot to say what language you are using (java or Kotlin), and what you have tried so far.

Comment: @BooberBunz I've tried a sample in Java. It says the ₹.125.50 as "point one two five rupees point five zero"